# Mathcal fonts in Times New Roman environment

Tags: fonts, environments

I am typing a document where the preset font style is Times New Roman. As a result the `\mathcal` fonts looks as `\mathscr` fonts.

Is it possible to define somehow the usual mathcal fonts (even for a particular letter only) without altering the rest of the environment?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: There are quite a few Times (New) Roman text and math fonts out there. Which ones would you be using? And, do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  In `unicode-math`, you can use the command:

```
\setmathfont[ range={cal, bfcal},
              Scale = MatchUppercase
            ]{STIX Two Math}
```

Or any other math font of your choice.  To get the default `\mathcal` alphabet, replace `STIX Two Math` with `Latin Modern Math`.

If you need to use legacy fonts, the best way to change the script alphabets is with `mathalpha` (formerly `mathalfa`).  For example, you could load the package with:

```
\usepackage[cal = txupr]{mathalpha}
```

To get the TX upright `\mathcal` letters.  You can also give the `calscaled =` option if necessary to make them match the height of the other fonts.  Check out [the manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) for font specimens.

You could also load a legacy font package, for example `eucal` to load Euler Script as `\mathcal`.